# modificar ícone de notificação

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Alguém me explica por quê o ícone da minha notificação está pequeno e a notificação quando "chega" não vibra nem faz nenhum som? Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

public MyFirebaseMessagingService(){

}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: Message Received: \n" +
            "Title: " + title + "\n" +
            "Message: " + message);

    sendNotification(title, message);

}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages(){

}



private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification note = notificationBuilder.build();
    note.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    notificationManager.notify(0, note);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quanto ao tamanho do ícone, você pode acrescentar isto ao seu `notificationBuilder`:

```
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
```

E para vibrar quando chega a notificação, a alteração fica assim:

```
Notification note = notificationBuilder.build();
note.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
note.sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

notificationManager.notify(0, note);
```

Assim, você pode remover o `setSound()` lá de cima também.

Comment: Modifiquei tudo o que o senhor disse, mas a mandar a notificação através do firebase continua tudo igual. Obrigado

Comment: Pode acrescentar à sua pergunta a atualização de como ficou o seu código com minha sugestão?

Comment: Já fiz a edição do código, mas não será preciso actualizar alguma coisa no Firebase para as alterações que eu fiz sejam actualizadas, é que cada vez que eu faço alteração no meu código e vou ao Firebase para testar, aparece sempre da mesma forma!? Obrigado